# How to get browser data in MARSHMALLOW

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Since MARSHMALLOW has stopped granting access to BROSWER_DATA, is there any other way to get browser data?

Regards

Comment: what data in particular, and isn't there more information in the article that states access is no longer granted?

Comment: Yup yup, its in android documentation, that its no longer granted, but i am sure there must be some tweeks around to get the URLs from browser browsed

Comment: self-quoting: `what data in particular`?

Comment: @njzk2 - The URLs that end user browsed

Comment: indeed, it looks like this was in the `Browser` class, but there isn't much left there!